# Как слить значения 2-х массивов по индексам?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть конкретный массив 'data' из 20 строк

```js
 var data = [['classique'], ['City'], ['Radouga'], ['Hypermarche'], ['Atak'], ['U. Proximite'], ['Proximite'], ['Auchan Retail Russie'],
          ['Total'],['classique'], ['City'], ['Radouga'], ['Hypermarche'], ['Atak'], ['U. Proximite'], ['Proximite'], ['Specialise'], ['Ecommerce'], ['Auchan Retail Russie']];
```

И есть массив с данными 'gridData' тоже из 20 строк я его перебираю и добавляю в в массив 'data' Добавляются как еще строки массива.

```js
var data = [['classique'], ['City'], ['Radouga'], ['Hypermarche'], ['Atak'], ['U. Proximite'], ['Proximite'], ['Auchan Retail Russie'],
            ['Total'],['classique'], ['City'], ['Radouga'], ['Hypermarche'], ['Atak'], ['U. Proximite'], ['Proximite'], ['Specialise'], ['Ecommerce'], ['Auchan Retail Russie']];
for(var i = 0; i < this.gridData.length; i++) {
    data[i].push(this.gridData[i].data);
```

Как сделать так чтобы первая строка 'gridData' добавлялась в первую строку 'data' вторая строка 'gridData' во вторую 'data' и так далее. 
щас массив делается таким data =[comparable [значения gridData'0']], [classique [значения gridData'1']] итд а мне необходимо вот так [comporable, значения gidData'0'], [classicue, значения gridData'1'] итд

Comment: нет не так. Приведи пример входных данных. не нужно все 20. Входные данные это переменная `data`, переменная `this.gridData`. И пример выходных данных. То есть, что в итоге должно быть в переменной `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[метод push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) добавляет элементы в конец массива. Для добавления значения в конкретный элемент, нужно к нему обратиться по индексу:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.gridData.length; i++) {
    data[i].push(this.gridData[i].data);
```

---

Если в *this.gridData[i].data* хранится массив, **все** элементы которого нужно добавить в *data[i]* то стоит применить [spread оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.gridData.length; i++) {
    data[i].push(...this.gridData[i].data);
```

Либо, если данный оператор еще не поддерживается, использовать метод [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.gridData.length; i++) {
    data[i].push.apply(data[i], this.gridData[i].data);
```

Comment: @Gruby спасибо большое помогло

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛюбимов, посмотри обновленный ответ, судя по всему это именно то, что ты хотел